# Change live code in iframe on button click

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Any buddy please help me...
i want java-script that change code in iframe

> `<body>`
>   `<button>Change Code</button>`
>   `<iframe src="1.html">`
>   `#document`
>   `<html><head></head><body><form>`
>   `<div class="abc">`
>
> ---
>
> `<div class="xyz">`
>   `Name :`
>   `<div class="form">`
>   `<input name="txt_name" type="text" id="txt_name" class="forms" >`
>   `</div>`
>   `</div>`
>
> ---
>
> `</div>`
>   `</form></body></html>`
>   `</iframe>`
>   `</body>`

I want to change code containing in `<div class="xyz">` replace with

> `<div class="xyz">`
>   `User Name :`
>   `<input name="txt_name" type="text" id="txt_name" class="forms" >`
>   `</div>`

on clicking change code button...
script should run on button click

Comment: Answer for this quection i got... `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<body>
<button id='button1' onclick="changecode()">

Change Code</button><br />

<iframe id='iframe1' src='1.html'>
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changecode(){
    $('#iframe1').contents().find('div.xyz').load('2.html');
}
</script>
</body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this...

Give your iframe an id e.g.: id="iframe1" and give your button and id. Eg : id="button1"

Then with jQuery you can do :

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
   $('#iframe').contents().find('.xyz').html('User Name : <input name="txt_name" type="text" id="txt_name" class="forms" >');
});
```

Regards

Comment: That's a question which has no accepted answers? And it doesn't entirely solve what the OP is seeking?

Comment: You're right I've updated my answer to actual code.

Comment: It change complete iframe  code. I want to change specific code in`<div class="xyz">`

Comment: still it not working...

Comment: ok...i Found The Problem... & i am updating code....